# Python pandas: merging partially overlapping dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, `df1`, like:

```
name | group | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5
id1  | G1    |
id2  | G1    |
id3  | G1    |
id4  | G2    |
id5  | G2    |
id6  | G2    |
...
id10
```

- The values of `col1`, `col2`, etc. are floats, >= 0.
- Values of `name` are strings, where each name uniquely identifies each row
- Values of `group` are strings. This column describes a grouping of the names, and is included for completeness.

And another dataframe, `df2`, like:

```
name | group | col2 | col4 | col5 | col7 |
id11 | G1    |
id12 | G1    |
id13 | G1    |
id14 | G2    |
id15 | G2    |
id16 | G2    |
...
id20
```

- There are no common `name` values between `df1` and `df2`.
- `df2.group` also comprises of either values `G1` or `G2`
- The columns of `df2` can be either a part of `df1` (e.g. `col2`, `col4` and `col5`), or unique to `df2` (e.g. `col7`).

I wish to merge these two dataframes like so:

```
name | group | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col7
id1  | G1    |                                  |  0
id2  | G1    |                                  |  0
id3  | G1    |                                  |  0
id4  | G2    |                                  |  0
...
id10 | G2    |  0   |      |  0   |      |      |
id11 | G1    |  0   |      |  0   |      |      |
id12 | G1    |  0   |      |  0   |      |      |
...
id20
```

- Append the rows of `df2` to `df1`, and get the set union of their columns.
- If a row from the originating dataframe has no value under a new column, then it would have a zero value in the merged dataframe. e.g. There is not `col7` in `df1`, so in the merged dataframe, all the rows that originated from `df1` would get the value 0 under the `col7`. Same for all the rows that originated from `df2`, and the columns `col1` and `col3`, which are unique to `df1`.

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be much easier than I thought:

```
df_union_all= pd.concat([df1, df2])
```